# Can i use thenCombine/thenCompose on a CompletableFuture more than once?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, completable-future

Suppose I have CompletableFutures A, B and C is a runnable. B depends on A and C depends on A and B, can I do A thenCompose B and B thenCombine A so C gets the value from A and B even though B depended on the value from A also?

Basically what I'm asking is - is there a way to get a CompletableFuture pipeline like this:

```
A -- B -- C
  -------^

CompletableFuture<String> A = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> return "Hello");
CompletableFuture<String> B = A.thenApplyAsync(stringA -> return stringA + "World");
B.thenCombine(A, (stringA, StringB) -> doStuffWithAAndB(stringA, stringB));
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you showed some actual code, rather than trying to describe your code.

Comment: Added code snippet.

Comment: From what I can see, you have `A` sending it's output to `B`, and then B takes this as input and sends output to C. So if you also need the output from `A` to go to `C`, then do that from `B` because `B` already has `A`'s output

Comment: @smac89 I thought about doing that but that may result in deep nested callback structures which i was trying to avoid. Is it against CompletableFuture threading model to depend on one twice (ie undefined behavior) or just something we should avoid design wise?

Comment: My suggestion then will be to make `A` return a Supplier which when called yields the result of `A`. This will allow you to in a sense get the result of `A` as many times as you wish. This all comes down to the fact that B and C need the result of A before they can proceed, so I will suggest either making A synchronous and then give that result to B and C, or merge B into C so that the async result from A is processed within C, which returns a future that waits for B and then does the work of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to do this. There is no restriction on how you combine `CompletableFuture`s together.

It is your responsibility to make sure they eventually complete, but it is not an issue here.

Alternatively, you can access A directly from a callback, like this:

```
CompletableFuture<String> a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> return "Hello");
CompletableFuture<String> b = a.thenApplyAsync(stringA -> return stringA + "World");
b.thenApply(stringB -> doStuffWithAAndB(a.join(), stringB));
```

but this is really a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [RxJava2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava%20RxJava2), you can do it as follows:

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;

public class CompletableFutureDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CompletableFuture<String> a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello");
        Observable<String> obsA = Observable.fromFuture(a);

        Observable<String> obsB = obsA.map(stringA -> stringA + " world");

        Observable.zip(obsA, obsB, (stringA, stringB) -> {
            return stringA + " " + stringB;
        })
        .subscribe(zipped -> {
            System.out.println(zipped);
        });
    }
```